# jQuery each function not working

Tags: jquery, function, each

I've got some `p` tags with the class `PointsToggle`

```
<p class="PointsToggle">POINTS STATEMENT - AVAILABLE 7AM TOMORROW</p>
<p class="PointsToggle">SOME OTHER TEXT</p>
```

And some jQuery like this

```
$('.PointsToggle').each(function() {
if ($(this).text = 'POINTS STATEMENT - AVAILABLE 7AM TOMORROW') {
    $(this).css('width', '510px');
}
else {
    $(this).css('width', '20px');
}
})​
```

But I can't seem to get it to work

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('.PointsToggle').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.text() == 'POINTS STATEMENT - AVAILABLE 7AM TOMORROW') {
    $this.width(510);
  } else {
    $this.width(20);
  }
})​
```

Comment: Catch `$(this)` into a local variable at the start of function.

Comment: well, I meant catch...catch into a variable to cache the value.

Answer (score 3):

You are using = which means assign.  Try == instead.

Answer (score 2):

[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is a function, so you're missing some parenthesis when calling it, like this:

```
if ($(this).text() == 'POINTS STATEMENT - AVAILABLE 7AM TOMORROW') {
```

Or a bit simpler overall in jQuery 1.4+:

```
$('.PointsToggle').width(function() {
 return $(this).text() == 'POINTS STATEMENT - AVAILABLE 7AM TOMORROW' ? 510 : 20;
})​;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready() {
    $('.PointsToggle').each(function() {
        if($(this).html() == 'POINTS STATEMENT - AVAILABLE 7AM TOMORROW') {
            $(this).width(510);
        } else {
            $(this).width(20);
        }
    })​
});
```

#### EDIT:

If it's possible I would have the code generating the html add another class. Then this can all be done with css. For example:

```
<p class="PointsToggle Toggled">POINTS STATEMENT - AVAILABLE 7AM TOMORROW</p>

<style>
    .PointsToggle {width:20px;}
    .PointsToggle.Toggled {width:510px;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$('.PointsToggle').each(function() {
if ($(this).text() == 'POINTS STATEMENT - AVAILABLE 7AM TOMORROW') {
    $(this).css('width', '510px');
}
else {
    $(this).css('width', '20px');
}
})​
```