# jQuery live function not working

Tags: jquery, function, live

Further to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922887/jquery-each-function-not-working) I need to add in the `.live()` function as i'm adding the content dynamically

This is what I have now

```
$('.PointsToggle').live('each',function() {
              $this = $(this);
              if ($this.text() == 'POINTS STATEMENT - AVAILABLE 7AM TOMORROW') {
                $this.width(510);
              } else {
                $this.width(20);
              }
            })
```

But this doesn't seem to work now

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: Unless you have a really, really good reason for making `$this` either an (implicit) global or using it from a containing scope, add a `var` in front of it in the anonymous function. Other than that, "each" is not an event, see tandu's answer for details.

Comment: I'm confused what kind of event you are trying to bind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of thing you will need the [livequery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

```
$('.PointsToggle').livequery(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.text() == 'POINTS STATEMENT - AVAILABLE 7AM TOMORROW') {
    $this.width(510);
   } else {
    $this.width(20);
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind event handlers with `.live()`, which 'each' is not.  This should work:

```
$('.PointsToggle').live('load', function () { $(this).each(function () { ... }); });
```

Comment: Hmm that's a tough one. I'm not sure what even handler to use.  In the click function, I chained .ready() to .appentTo() and that seemed to work, but it seems strange to me.

Answer (score -2):

I think you probably want to replace '$this' with a 'var thisObject':

```
$('.PointsToggle').live('each',function() {
          var thisObject = $(this);
          if (thisObject.text() == 'POINTS STATEMENT - AVAILABLE 7AM TOMORROW') {
            thisObject.width(510);
          } else {
            thisObject.width(20);
          }
        })
```

Answer (score -2):

you can  use each  method in a event like click that  mean which you can use this method in a body of a event like this

```
$("#Prefactor_save").live('click', function () {
    var tmp = "";
    alert(tmp);
    $("#factor_tb td").each(function () {
        tmp += $(this).val() + ",";
    });
    $("#factor_tb selected:option").each(function () {
        tmp += $(this).text() + ",";
    });
    alert(tmp);
});
```

in this sample I use each function in a click event.